# Polynomial division in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+x+3\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+x+3\rangle.$
>
> $1.$ Find a $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ with $\deg(f(x)) <3$ such that $[f(x)] = [x^5 + 3x^3+2x+4]$ in $R.$
>
> $2.$ Find the multiplicative inverse of $[x^4+2x^3+x+4]$ in $R.$
>
> $3.$ Find the multiplicative inverse of $[x^2+1]$ in $R.$

$1.$

In $R,$ $[x^3+x^2+x+3]=[0].$ So $[x^5+x^4+x^3+3x^2]=[0].$ We now proceed to simplify $[x^5 + 3x^3+2x+4]$ in $R.$
$$[x^5 + 3x^3+2x+4]-[x^5+x^4+x^3+3x^2]=[4x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+4]-[4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+2x]=[3x^3+3x^2+4]-[3x^3+3x^2+3x+4]=[2x].$$

Since $\deg (2x)<3$ and $[2x]=[x^5+3x^3+2x+4],$ $\boxed{f(x)=2x}.$

$2.$

We simplify $[x^4+2x^3+x+4]$ in $R.$ We have that $$[x^4+2x^3+x+4]=[x^4+2x^3+x+4]-[x^4+x^3+x^2+3x]\\
=[x^3+4x^2+3x+4]-[x^3+x^2+x+3]\\
=[3x^2+2x+1].$$

By long division, in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x],(3x^2+2x+1)(2x+4)+4+x=x^3+x^2+x+3\; (1).$

By long division, in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x],$ $3x^2+2x+1=(4+x)(3x)+1\Rightarrow 4(3x^2+2x+1)=(4+x)(4(3x))+4.$

So in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle3x^2+2x+1\rangle, 
[4][0]=[0]=[4+x][4(3x)]+4\Rightarrow [4+x][2x]=[1]\Rightarrow [4+x]^{-1}=[2x].$

So, multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $2x,$ we have that in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x],$ $$(2x)(x^3+x^2+x+3)=(3x^2+2x+1)(2x+4)(2x)+(4+x)(2x)\\
=(3x^2+2x+1)(4x^2+3x)+4(3x^2+2x+1)+1\\
\Rightarrow 4(2x)(x^3+x^2+x+3) = (3x^2+2x+1)(4(4x^2+3x+4))+4\\
=(3x^2+2x+1)(x^2+2x+1)+4.$$
Thus, in $R,$ $$[4][2x][0]=[0]=[3x^2+2x+1][x^2+2x+1]+[4]\Rightarrow [3x^2+2x+1][x^2+2x+1]=[1]\Rightarrow \boxed{[x^4+2x^3+x+4]^{-1}=[3x^2+2x+1]^{-1}=[x^2+2x+1]}.$$

$3.$

Since $\deg(x^2+1)<3,$ we just need to divide $x^3+x^2+x+3$ by $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ to determine the inverse. Doing so yields $x^3+x^2+x+3=(x^2+1)(x+1)+2\Rightarrow (x^2+1)\cdot2(x+1)+4=2(x^3+x^2+x+3).$ Thus, in $R,$ $[x^2+1][2(x+1)]+[4]=[0]\Rightarrow [x^2+1][2x+2]=[1].$ Thus, $\boxed{[x^2+1]^{-1} = [2x+2]}.$

> Edit: I think I finally found the inverses! yay. However, are these the only inverses? I’m pretty sure multiplicative inverses are unique in a ring.

Comment: $x^3+x^2+x+3=(x^2+1)(x+1)+2$, so $(x^2+1)(x+1)=-2=3$. So $(x^2+1)2(x+1)=6=1$.

Comment: Yeah use Euclidean algorithm to find inverse. There's several examples in this site on how to do it.

Comment: @take008 I got the inverses (I'm pretty sure they're correct too), but I was wondering if there was a shorter approach?

Comment: You can do it by inspection, but most of the time it's hard to do it that way as you saw in this problem. Euclidean algorithm should always work as long as you have that the polynomial is indeed a unit in the quotient ring.

Comment: Inverses are unique in any monoid. Let $xy = yx = 1$ and $xz = zx = 1$. Then $y = y(xz) = (yx)z = z$. This actually shows a bit more: if $x$ has both left and right inverse, then they are equal.

Comment: Yeah, you can check that $x^3+x^2+x+3$ is irreducible, since it's a polynomial of degree $3$ and has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Thus the ideal generated by the polynomial is maximal. Therefore, the quotient ring is a field, and there you know that inverses are unique.

Comment: @take008, that's quite an elaborate explanation for something that holds in general. And begs the question: why are inverses unique in a field?

Comment: @Ennar What is a monoid? Why is this quotient ring a monoid w.r.t multiplication? The reason I proved it that way, is because I took a peek at OP's posting history, and I only used definitions that I am certain OP knows.

Comment: @take008, a monoid is an algebraic structure with a binary operation satisfying associativity and existence of identity element (axioms OP surely knows). Any ring with identity is a monoid wrt multiplication by ring axioms. As a consequence, multiplicative inverses are unique in any unital ring, not just fields. If you read my comment above yours, this is a very simple thing to prove, simpler than checking irreducibility of a polynomial. But the reason why I addressed you is that your comment is misleading in a sense that it seems that you need to have a field to have unique inverse.